# Undefined reference to pthread_atfork`

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, openmpi

Using g++ version 4.9 in Ubuntu, when compiling a C++ source file named `test.cpp` that needs a shared library named `libUtils.so` (which in its turn needs Open MPI shared library, hence the parameter `-Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib` ) as follows:

```
g++ test.cpp -lUtils -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib
```

An error is thrown `/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libopen-pal.so.20: undefined reference to pthread_atfork`.

I passed `-pthread` and `-lpthread` to g++ but none of these solved the error.

Comment: "I passed -pthread and -lpthread"  What's the full line you use.  Order matters.

Comment: I tried many combinations and none worked, namely: `g++ test.cpp -pthread -lUtils -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib`, `g++ test.cpp -lpthread -lUtils -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib`, `g++ test.cpp -lUtils -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib -pthread` and `g++ test.cpp -lUtils -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib -lpthread`.

Comment: `g++ test.cpp -lpthread -lUtils` links to pthread and then utils - meaning utils can't find the pthread library.  go the other way around.

Comment: Did you build Open MPI (and which version ?) on the very same machine ? Did you upgrade any package after that ? What does `ldd /home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libopen-pal.so.20` says ? Does `test.cpp` invokes any MPI subroutine ? What if you link with `mpicxx` instead ?

Comment: @UKMonkey: both `g++ test.cpp -lpthread -lUtils` and `g++ test.cpp -lUtils -lpthread` do not work.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: I built Open MPI 2.1.3 on the very same machine. No upgrade of any package after that. The result of running `ldd` is the following: `
lol@machine:~/$ ldd dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libopen-pal.so.20
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7723000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf760a000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7601000)
 libutil.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0xf75fd000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf744c000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x565e2000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf742f000)`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: as you can conclude from my previous comment, the library `pthread` can be successfully seen/loaded by `libopen-pal.so.20`. Any idea of what is going on here?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version ? Is gcc 4.9 the compiler that comes with the distro ?

Comment: Can you try to append `-lpthread_nonshared` to your link command and see whether it helps ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: Ubuntu 14.04 which comes with GCC 4.9 (i.e. I did not update it).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: unfortunately `-lpthread_nonshared` did not work either.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I am having the same problem.