# Error when using Open MPI shared library in a C program compiled by g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, openmpi

I have successfully built Open MPI version 2.1.3 from scratch in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit and using GCC 4.9. The result was the following shared libraries (needed for a program to use Open MPI):

```
dummy@machine:~/$ ldd /home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libmpi.so /home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libopen-rte.so /home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libopen-pal.so

/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libmpi.so:
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffecfb87000)
libopen-rte.so.20 => not found
libopen-pal.so.20 => not found
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fcc99058000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcc98d51000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcc98b33000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcc9876a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005574ed2b8000)

/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libopen-rte.so:
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc99743000)
libopen-pal.so.20 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff6f498f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff6f45c6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005622db738000)

/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libopen-pal.so:
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdfc374000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f46b6bb5000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f46b69ad000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f46b67aa000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f46b63e0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055eca0708000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f46b61c2000)
```

Now, when I try to compile a small program with g++ version 4.9 using Open MPI shared library it fails with an `/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib/libopen-pal.so: undefined reference to pthread_atfork` error. The small program is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(void)
{
    MPI_Comm comm;
    int rank;

    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
    printf("<%d>\n", rank);

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation statement is:

```
g++ test.c -pthread -I/home/dummy/openmpi/build/include -L/home/dummy/openmpi/build/lib -lmpi -lopen-rte -lopen-pal
```

Any idea why g++ (i.e. C++ compiler) is throwing the aforementioned error? FYI, when I compile the same program with gcc (i.e. C compiler) it works perfectly.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages and not every C program is a valid C++ program. The subset of C that is valid C++ is not the entire language. The subset of C that is valid C++ with *the same semantics* is even smaller. Build C code as C, not C++ (except for *very* special cases with good reason).

Comment: In this case, the small program is valid both in C and C++. The issue that I am trying to find a solution for is due to a linking problem and not a compilation one (therefore, g++ can compile it without problems).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to pthread\_atfork\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987587/undefined-reference-to-pthread-atfork)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: yes, possible duplicate Gilles; but to post a possible solution for the issue that would have been much more interesting from your side, especially because you are one of the developers of Open MPI which does not compile well with g++. Better to switch to MPICH where there are no issues with g++. Smooth!

Comment: some more info was requested to you on the Open MPI devel list, and I will investigate this when they are provided (and the server is back too). meanwhile, if MPICH works for you, then go for it!

Comment: Thanks for investigating this Gilles. All the information that I have is actually posted in this page, which I believe is clear and stripped to the minimum to actually reproduce the issue. Please let me know if you need additional info and I will be glad to provide it.